# No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Tags: macos, ssd

um...i don't know what happened..

I just opened lid to wake up my mac then it freezed. I re-booted it and now i'm seeing "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

i'm using intel 320 ssd 120gb.

Should I re-install mac os again? How can I make sure that it won't happen again?

Comment: this is so stupid...i just re-booted and pressed option key..now i can boot. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible the drive is failing. Before doing anything else, backup your data. Holding the option key brings up the startup manager which shows any available volumes.

Do you have multiple drives connected to your computer? Maybe it is trying to boot using the wrong drive.

Comment: Agree, sounds to me like the drive is failing. Sadly, SSD drives don't seem to have a great lifespan, as yet:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, try the solution that user "Moon" mentionned as comment of his question:

**1. Whilst holding down the "alt" button, press the Power button.**

**2. Once you see the icon of the hard drive, click on it.**

If above procedure doesn't work, extract the hard drive, put it in an external enclosure and check with the disk utility of another Mac.

Comment: Context: I had similar issue than the user who asked the question with a MacBook Pro 15'' A1226 from 2007 running OS X Snow Leopard. The MacBook had been shut down as it was awaking from hibernation. Then, the `No bootable device — insert boot disk and press any key` message appeared when restarting the MacBook. The hard disk and the filesystem had been checked with an external enclosure and were both OK. The simple trick of manually selecting the hard drive by using the `alt` option key solved the problem.